# How to show other objects from json in Android

Tags: android, json

I want develop android application for one website. I read website posts from `json` and show its in `RecyclerView` every 10 posts.
I can show title, description and thumbnail. but i want show **medium** from **thumbnail_images** instance of **thumbnail**. I don't know how to read images from **medium** ?!

**My Json Link :**  [Link](http://tellfa.com/tafrihgah/?json=get_posts&count=10&page=1)

**AsyncTaskCodes:**

```
public class MainDataInfo {
    private Context mContext;
    private String ServerAddress = ServerIP.getIP();

    public void getMainDataInfo(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        new getInfo().execute(ServerAddress + "page=1");
    }

    private class getInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        EventBus bus = EventBus.getDefault();
        private String ou_response;
        private List<MainDataModel> infoModels;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            CustomProcessDialog.createAndShow(mContext);
            infoModels = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(ServerAddress + "page=1")
                    .build();

            Response response;
            try {
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                ou_response = response.body().string();
                response.body().close();
                if (ou_response != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject postObj = new JSONObject(ou_response);
                        JSONArray postsArray = postObj.getJSONArray("posts");
                        infoModels = new ArrayList<>();

                        for (int i = 0; i <= infoModels.size(); i++) {
                            JSONObject postObject = (JSONObject) postsArray.get(i);
                            int id = postObject.getInt("id");
                            String title = postObject.getString("title");
                            Log.d("Data", "Post id: " + id);
                            Log.d("Data", "Post title: " + title);

                            //Use the title and id as per your requirement
                                infoModels.add(new MainDataModel(
                                        postObject.getInt("id"),
                                        postObject.getString("title"),
                                        postObject.getString("content"),
                                        postObject.getString("thumbnail")));

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return ou_response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            CustomProcessDialog.dissmis();
            if (result != null) {
                bus.post(infoModels);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can set images from **medium** ? thanks all <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
        JSONObject postObj = new JSONObject(ou_response);
        JSONArray postsArray = postObj.getJSONArray("posts");
        for (int i= 0; i < postsArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject postObject = postsArray.getJSONObject(i);
            int id = postObject.getInt("id");
            String title = postObject.getString("title");
            //get other data
            JSONObject imageObj = postObject.getJSONObject("thumbnail_images");
            JSONObject mediumObj = imageObj.getJSONObject("medium");
            String mediumImage = mediumObj.getString("url");
            Log.d("Data", "id: " + id);
            Log.d("Data", "title: " + title);
            //log other data
            Log.d("Data", "the mediumObj url: " + mediumImage);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Elaborating a little bit on this would probably make a better impression and larger likelihood of up votes.

Comment: @DaiDong, tnx for your help but when added this codes :                             `JSONObject imageObj = postObject.getJSONObject("thumbnail_images");
                            JSONObject mediumObj = imageObj.getJSONObject("medium");
                            String mediumImage = mediumObj.getString("url");` and set `postObject.getString(mediumImage)));` not show any post in my application! how can fix it?

Comment: @F_Feed I run it in my project and have no problem, did you have any log ? And the code `String mediumImage = mediumObj.getString("url")`,already get the images from medium . I think you will get how to use JSON，it`s not a difficulty work.No matter how complex, be wrapped by `{}` use JSONObject, and `[]` use JSONArrary.